# How do you create a MVC view for navigation properties (one to many, many to many)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many, crud, navigation-properties

I have two ASP.NET MVC EF entities sharing an association:

[image]

When I am editing or creating the `User`, I'd like to be able to attach one or more `UserRole`s. So, my `User` `Create` view looks like this:

```
@model MyModels.UserViewModel
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Create"; }
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>User</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)
        </div>

        <!-- how to create an editor to add/remove roles -->
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserRoles)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserRoles)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserRoles)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Since `Model.UserRoles` is initially empty, I get nothing in this line `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserRoles)`. I tried adding a drop-down where I can select existing roles using JavaScript (I guess retrieved as partial view?), but I don't know how to append a selected role to the `fieldset` so that it gets submitted.

How is this usually done in ASP.NET? I have been searching SO for a while but cannot find the appropriate solution.

To clarify, what I don't understand is how to add/append a new role to the client side, so that the submit button actually sends this inside the `UserRoles` list.

**(edit) Ok, I've found this:** [How to add an item to a list in a ViewModel using Razor and .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36317362/how-to-add-an-item-to-a-list-in-a-viewmodel-using-razor-and-net-core). It says that I should fetch a partial view which is written to look like the inputs which would be generated by `@Html.EditorFor` (with the next array index), and then append it using JavaScript.

That looks quite weird, is that really the correct approach?

Comment: You should not use the Entity models for views for this reason. Your view should rather use a view-model to separate your layers. In your view-model you can have a list of roles that get passed to your controller along with the user id. Lemme know if you require an example.

Comment: @Vince: thanks, actually `MyModels.UserViewModel` is a view model (it was misspelled), and I don't have a problem with passing the list of all roles, my real issue is how to add multiple roles to `UserRoles` on the client side and get this list in the controller method. It seems like binding a collection is quite painful in ASP.NET MVC, most examples use the `BeginCollectionItem` helper from github. Could you please provide an example of how this part is done?